# Angular : how refresh list after modal use?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have an employee list (ng-repeat), i can update employee info with modal. but when i click on save button, the list is not updated (i must press F5).

I try to use $watch but without succes

there are my controllers (list and modal) :

```
var employee = angular.module('employee.module', [
    'app.common.module',
    'employee.services',
    'employee.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);
employee.controller('EmployeeCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    'EmployeeServices',
    EmployeeCtrl
]);

function EmployeeCtrl($scope, $log, EmployeeServices) {


    $scope.retrieveEmp = function(){
        // retrieve employee list  --> OK
        return $scope.lesEmployees = EmployeeServices.getEmployees();
    }
    // $scope.$watch('retrieveEmp');
    $scope.retrieveEmp();

   $scope.$watch($scope.lesEmployees);

  /*...*/

}

  /*   MODAL controller for update or visu */
employee.controller('ModalCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    'EmployeeServices',
   '$stateParams',
    ModalCtrl
]);

function ModalCtrl ($scope, $log, EmployeeServices, $stateParams) {
    // display infos in modal --> OK
    EmployeeServices.getDetail($stateParams.id).$getPromise().then(

        function(detailEMP) {
            $scope.detailEmployee = detailEMP;
        },

        function() {
            $scope.detailEmployee = [];
            $scope.totalItems = 0;
        }
    );

    // close button
    $scope.close = function() { $scope.$close(true); };

    // update button
    $scope.ok = function(){
        EmployeeServices.updateEmp($scope.detailEmployee).$getPromise().then(

            $scope.close()
        )
    };
};

})();
```

I don't understand how to use $watch, i don't find example using modal. 
In which controller must i use $watch ?

Or simply, is $watch the right way ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: When you update the employee details, you dont change the `$scope.lesEmployee`. That's why the list dont modify. It is not necessary to use the `$watch` in your case.

Comment: Ok berterraba,

so i try to update the list by updating the modal controller like this :

    $scope.ok = function(){
            EmployeeServices.updateEmp($scope.detailEmployee).$getPromise().then(
                $scope.lesEmployees = EmployeeServices.getEmployees()
                ,
                $scope.close()
            )

        };


now, i have this message in console.

    "GET http ://localhost:8080/AppBackEnd/api/empl/list/ 500 (Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.)"

Comment: That's another problem (problably something with your session cookies).

Comment: Can you please add code for your 'EmployeeServices'

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the problem but i find another way to update my list !

```
function ModalCtrl ($scope, $log, EmployeeServices, $stateParams, $rootScope ) {

   //   get detail   
   EmployeeServices.getDetail($stateParams.id).$getPromise().then(
        function(detailEMP) {
            $log.info("retrieve liste, date = " + detailEMP.hireDate);
            $scope.detailEmployee = detailEMP;
        }
    );

    //   close modal 
    $scope.close = function() { $scope.$close(true); };


    //   update list 
    var updateEmployees = function (item) {

        for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.lesEmployees.length; ++i) {

            if ($rootScope.lesEmployees[i].idemployee === item.idemployee) {
                $rootScope.lesEmployees[i] = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }        

    $scope.ok = function(){
        EmployeeServices.updateEmp($scope.detailEmployee).$getPromise().then(
            function(updateItem) {
                // updateItem is a boolean
                // true -> update OK
                // false -> update KO
                updateEmployees($scope.detailEmployee);
            }
        );
        $scope.close();

    };

};
```

It works fine !!